# Insert multiple rows when click Submit Button in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to insert multiple rows when click the submit button.and there is one row and add button.when click add button it will add another row.now i need to submit all the row values by clicking the submit button at once.

[image]

according to above picture there is an error. then when i click the add button data inserted the database. but i used to add button only for add empty field set. not for the submit form. and i have only one dropdown for project name. and now i want to insert project id for all rows . any one can plz help me. thank you. my code is below.

**view**

```
<!--form open-->            

    <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="frmadd" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/boq_controller/create" method="POST">
<!--project-->


<span><b>Project Name</b></span>
    <?php
       $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "project" style="width:100%; height:35px;"';
        echo form_dropdown('project[]',$project, set_value('project'), $attributes);?>

 <!--project-->

    <!-- boq_tbl // field list-->
   <table class="table" id="boq_tbl">
        <thead>
          <th>Item No</th>
          <th>Description</th> 
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Unit</th>
          <th>Rate</th>
          <th>Laboure Hrs</th>
          <th>Labour Cost</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
       <thead>

       <tbody>
<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="frmadd" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/boq_controller/create" method="POST">


    <tr class="txtMult">

       <td><input type="text" name="work_product_id[]" class="form-control" id="work_product_id" placeholder="" style="width:60px;" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="work_item_description[]" class="form-control" id="work_item_description" placeholder="" style="width:350px;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="" class="form-control val1" style="width:80px;" /></td>
        <td><select style=" height: 28px; width: 70px; border-radius: 2px;" name="unit[]" >
            <option value="" selected> </option>
            <option value="cube">cube</option>
            <option value="sq.ft">sq.ft</option>
            <option value="Cwts">Cwts</option>
            <option value="Gal" >Gal</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" class="form-control val2" style="width:80px;"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="laboure_hrs[]" id="" class="form-control val3" style="width:80px;"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"name="laboure_cost[]" id="" class="form-control val4" style="width:80px;"/></td>


        <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtmultTotal" name="txtmultTotal[]" style="width:80px;" placeholder="0.00" class="multTotal">
<!--            <input type="text" class="multTotal" placeholder="0.00">-->
        </td>
        <td><?php                                           
//hidden value user session id
echo form_hidden('staff_id[]',($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']) );
?>  </td>
    </tr>

     </tbody>
       </table> 
<p align="right">
    Grand Total# <span id="grandTotal">0.00</span> <input type="text" id="txtgrandTotal" name="txtgrandTotal">
    <button id="insert-more" class="btn btn-primary" type="">ADD</button>

</p>

<div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn btn-success" value="submit">
                </div>

</form>
 </div>

 </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->
  </div>
  <!--/.main-inner-->
</div>
<!--/.main-->




<script>
//add rows
    $("#insert-more").click(function () {
     $("#boq_tbl").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr class="txtMult">';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
});

$("#boq_tbl").on("keyup", ".txtMult input", multInputs);

//function for get total and grand total
function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
        var val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
        var val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
        var val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
        var val4 = $('.val4', this).val();
         var total = (val1 * val2 ) + (val3 * val4);
        $('.multTotal',this).text(total);
        $('#txtmultTotal',this).val(total);
        mult += total;

    });
    $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
    $('#txtgrandTotal').val(mult);
}


</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    //fill data
    var btnedit='';
    var btndelete = '';
        fillgrid();
        // add data
        $("#frmadd").submit(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#loader").show();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:'POST',
                data:data
            }).done(function (data){
                $("#response").html(data);
                $("#loader").hide();
                fillgrid();
            });
        });



    function fillgrid(){
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/boq_controller/fillgrid',
            type:'GET'
        }).done(function (data){
            $("#fillgrid").html(data);
            $("#loader").hide();
            btnedit = $("#fillgrid .btnedit");
            btndelete = $("#fillgrid .btndelete");
            var deleteurl = btndelete.attr('href');
            var editurl = btnedit.attr('href');
            //delete record
            btndelete.on('click', function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var deleteid = $(this).data('id');

                if(confirm("are you sure")){
                    $("#loader").show();
                    $.ajax({
                    url:deleteurl,
                    type:'POST' ,
                    data:'id='+deleteid
                    }).done(function (data){
                     alert(deleteurl);   
                    $("#response").html(data);
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    fillgrid();
                    });
                }
            });



        });
    }

});
</script>
```

**controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Boq_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('boq_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

    }

//    load boq page
    public function index()
    {  
        $data['project'] = $this-> boq_model ->get_project();
      $this -> load -> view('include/header');  
      $this->load->view('boq/boq',$data);
      }
//    load boq page       


public function create(){

//    validate fields
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('work_product_id', 'Work Product Id', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('work_item_description', 'Work Item Description', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity', 'Quantity', 'required');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('rate', 'Rate', 'required|numeric');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('laboure_hrs', 'Laboure Hrs', 'required|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('laboure_cost', 'Laboure Cost', 'required|numeric');

           if ($_POST) 
   {
        $project_id=$this->input->post('project');
        $staff_id=$this->input->post('staff_id');
       $item_no=$this->input->post('work_product_id');
        $description=$this->input->post('work_item_description');
        $qty=$this->input->post('quantity');
        $unit=$this->input->post('unit');
        $rate=$this->input->post('rate');
        $laboure_hrs=$this->input->post('laboure_hrs');
        $laboure_cost=$this->input->post('laboure_cost');
        $amount=$this->input->post('txtmultTotal');
        $data = array();
       for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('work_product_id')); $i++)
        {
           $data[$i] = array(
               'project_id' => $project_id[$i],
               'staff_id' => $staff_id[$i],
               'item_no' => $item_no[$i],
               'description' => $description[$i],
               'qty' => $qty[$i],
                'unit' => $unit[$i],
             'rate' => $rate[$i],
             'laboure_hrs' => $laboure_hrs[$i],
               'laboure_cost' => $laboure_cost[$i],
               'amount' => $amount[$i],
            );
       }
        print_r($data);
        $this->boq_model->create($data);
    }

}   

}
```

**model**

```
class Boq_model extends CI_Model {


    //Get project name
    function get_project()     
    { 
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->select('project_name');
        $this->db->from('project');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();

        $project_id = array('-SELECT PROJECT NAME -');
        $project_name = array('-SELECT PROJECT NAME-');

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
        {
            array_push($project_id, $result[$i]->id);
            array_push($project_name, $result[$i]->project_name);
        }
        return $project_result = array_combine($project_id, $project_name);
    }



    function create($data) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('boq', $data);
}

}
```

Comment: where is preg_match() in your Code?

Comment: i didn't use preg match.

Comment: you do! why are you writing "when i click submit biutton or add button it display error message

preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given" then?

Comment: that error message is display becouse of [] in name "<td><input type="text" name="work_product_id[]" class="form-control" id="work_product_id" placeholder=""></td>" when i submit the form without []( "<td><input type="text" name="work_product_id" class="form-control" id="work_product_id" placeholder=""></td>)
it doesn't show the error,